# flash/flex applications: how can i strip trace messages?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, trace

how can I strip trace() messages from a flex and flash applications ?

I write flash and flex applications and i use a lot of trace messages for debugging, but when i product the actual swf i want it to be stripped from any trace messages.

thanks

Comment: Think about changing from trace to a more sophisticated logging method. Either debugging properly, or using something like the logging functions included in the SDK. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f0f.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you export a release build, it won't include the trace statements.  `Project->Export Release Build...`

I recommend doing this, rather than releasing debug builds, as the compiler will also strip all the debug information, leaving you with a substantially smaller file.

Comment: Note, if you are doing an Ant build, then the build is by default a release build.

Comment: Only for MXMLC... IIRC COMPC does debug by default in some versions of the SDK

Answer (score 6):

For Flex applications, use the compiler argument:

```
-omit-trace-statements=true
```

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional compilation : http://edsyrett.wordpress.com/2008/09/22/using-conditional-compilation-to-detect-debug-mode/

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Publisher has a "Omit Trace Actions" option on the "[Publisher Options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7bcea.html)
" menu.

Answer (score 1):

A *release-build* will **not** omit trace statements!

To omit trace statements in the Flash builder environment:
Place in your flex compiler arguments.

```
-omit-trace-statements=true -debug=false
```

On release build the compiled swf should exclude trace statements.

***IMPORTANT***
In order to have trace statements in the future, you have change the compiler settings back and restart Flash Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Just spent some time searching how to omit trace messages in a `Flex library project` using ANT.

My problem was that I successfully omitted trace messages of my Flash Builder projects, but the trace messages from my embedded swc still popped up.

For Flash Builder projects I'm using in ANT:

```
<mxmlc ...>
    ...
    <arg value="compiler.omit-trace-statements=true" />
</mxmlc>
```

But the `<arg ...` property was completely ignored when using in an `<compc>` task (generating the swc file which I used later on).
The solution finally was quite simple:

```
<compc 
    debug="false"
    compiler.debug="false">
    ...
</compc>
```

So to omit trace output coming from swc libraries, don't forget to set `debug=false`.